# Changing pip directory after Python3.7 update

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have installed Python 3.7 I can use Python 3.7 by typing `python3` command in terminal.

However if i type `pip --version` or `pip3 --version` it prints `pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)` in either case. So i cannot install packages to use with Python3.7

How can i set pip3 path and Python version to use it with Python3.7 ?

BTW i use Raspbian Stretch as OS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+different+python+versions

Comment: `python3 -m pip install [package name]`

Answer (score 0):

Your path is probably not properly configured. 
In general, it's best to leave system Python version untouched to avoid breaking things.

I would recommend using `pyenv` to manage and easily switch Python versions. It can easily work with virtual environments as well, or even as a substitute.

Install from here: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation